# How can I block the guard when registering a user in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am using default Laravel registration and every time I register a user, the system currently logs him in, which I don't want.

For some reason I thought I had this working but now testing I see the issue. Below is my register controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Mail;
use App\Mail\verifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'verifytoken' => Str::random(40),
            'role_id' => $data['role_id']
        ]);
        $thisUser = User::findOrFail($user->id);
        Session::flush('status', 'Please verify your email for account activation');
        $this->sendEmail($thisUser);

        return $user;
    }

    public function sendEmail($thisUser){
        Mail::to($thisUser['email'])->send(new verifyEmail($thisUser));
    }

    public function sendEmailDone($email, $verifytoken){

        User::where(['email'=>$email, 'verifytoken'=>$verifytoken])->update(['status'=>'1', 'verifytoken'=>NULL]);

        return redirect('/login');

    }

    public function verifyEmail(){
        return view('emails.veryEmail');
    }
}
```

User registers, an email is sent to him with a token, and he should only be allowed to login after he activates the token via email.

The only problem here is that the user is currently being logged in automatically.

I know there is line with the guard that normally logs the user, but I do not even have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trait `RegistersUsers` defines the register method:

```
/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

You'd need to override this and remove the `$this->guard()->login($user);` line.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, which applies if you are on Laravel 5.7 or can upgrade your project, would be to utilize Laravel's new user email verification system. It sounds like that's what' you're trying to build manually, but now it's included out of the box. Look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification) at the documentation. I think it will accomplish exactly what you're looking for.